# Getting a few tables together

Tags: r

I have three tables read into R as dataframes.

Table1:

```
Student ID   School_Name             Campus Area
   4356791          BCCS    Northwest Springdale
    03127.           BZS            South Vernon
    12437.          BCCS.           South Vernon
```

Table 2:

```
ProctorID.           Date.    Score.   Student ID      Form#
      0211        10/05/16     75.57        55612   25432178
      0211        10/17/16     83.04        55612   47135671
      5134        10/17/16     63.28        02613    2371245
```

Table 3:

```
ProctorID         First.       Last.              Campus Area
    O211.         Simone      Lewis.     Northwest Springdale 
    5134.          Mona.   Yashamito     Northwest Springdale 
    0712.        Steven.      Lewis.             South Vernon
```

I want to combine the data frames and create a table with the   scores next to each other for each area, by school name.  I want an  output like the following:

```
School_Name      Form#   Northwest Springdale    Southvernon   
      BCCS.   2543127.                 83.04.          63.25       
      BCCS.     35674.                 75.14.              *
       BZS.   5321567.                  65.2.           62.3
```

A particular form for a particular school may not have a score for a certain area. Any ideas? I have been playing with sqldf package. Also Is it possible to manipulate this in R without using any sql?

Comment: The last table looks a bit disoriented.  My apologies.

Comment: you can use `merge` (base), `join` (plyr), or any of the `full/left_join` (dplyr) functions to do this. what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thank you all for the fixes.

Comment: Seems like a use of merge (base) as stated already. Join the first two on student id then join that using proctor id to the last. Then cast to create the columns by campus area.

Comment: I am an education major.  New to R/SQL. I am not sure how to get the campus area names as columns. I was trying to do  a full join between table 1 and table 2. But that does not give me the scores by the campus area side by side.

Comment: Ok. Thanks all. I got the final table after merging or joining them by the columns. How do I cast the result by campus area? Any help. I got this so far: ProctorID Student ID school_name campus Area Date Score Form # First Last

Answer (score 0):

To cast, something like this:

```
library(reshape2)
casted_df <- dcast(df, ... ~ "Campus Area", value.var="Score.")
```

An example that seems to work for me:

```
df1 <- data.frame("StudentID" = 1:3, "SchoolName" = c("School1", "School2", "School3"), "Area" = c("Area1", "Area2", "Area3"))
df2 <- data.frame("StudentID" = 1:3, "Score" = 100:102, "Proctor" = 4:6)
df3 <- data.frame("Proctor" = 4:6, "Area" = c("Area1", "Area2", "Area3"), "Name" = c("John", "Jane", "Jim"))

combined <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = "StudentID")
combined2 <- merge(combined, df3, by.x = "Proctor", by.y="Proctor")

library(reshape2)
final <- dcast(combined2, ... ~ Area.x, value.var="Score")
```

[image: df image]